# eslint throws parsing error unexpected token on named export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have an index.js file which has the following named export in it.

```
export Main from './Main/Main'
```

However, eslint doesn't like this and throws the error

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token Main
```

I'm not sure why as the app is working properly and I believe that's valid syntax.

My .eslintrc file looks like this

```
{
  env: {
    es6: true,
    browser: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    "react",
  ],
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle" : [2, "always-multiline"],
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-extra-semi": 2,
    "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": [2, "always"],
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": [2, {selfClosing: "after-props", nonEmpty: "after-props"}],
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": [2, "never", {"allowMultiline": false}],
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": [2, {maximum: 3}],
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 2,
    "react/sort-prop-types": 2,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 2,
    "react/sort-comp": 2
  },
}
```

Comment: It's not valid syntax, as you can verify by looking at the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#table-42 . What the correct solution is depends on what `'./Main/Main'` exports and how it does it.

Comment: It's a syntax proposal, but you'll have to enable it I'd assume.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right. Got the idea from here https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/index.js Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out. It's an experimental feature so I need to enable babel-eslint as my eslint parser.

Now my .eslintrc looks like this

```
{
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  env: {
    es6: true,
    browser: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    "react",
  ],
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle" : [2, "always-multiline"],
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-extra-semi": 2,
    "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": [2, "always"],
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": [2, {selfClosing: "after-props", nonEmpty: "after-props"}],
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": [2, "never", {"allowMultiline": false}],
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": [2, {maximum: 3}],
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 2,
    "react/sort-prop-types": 2,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 2,
    "react/sort-comp": 2
  },
}
```

Comment: If that experimental feature is the only reason you need babel-eslint and you don't want to deal with the overhead, you can use `export { default as Main } from './Main/Main';`, which is valid ES6 and will work fine in the default parser.

Comment: @btmills That's a great insight. Thank you!

Comment: PLZ! Mark this is THE answer!

Answer (score 0):

since I got the same error for a different reason, here's where I went wrong:

If you're using babel with atom package development, babel is activated by a `use babel` at the beginning of every file.

`use babel`, much like `use strict` needs to be at the very beginning of the file! So much as a space in front of it will deactivate it, followed by the js engine tripping over your export statement or, similar ```unexpected token export````.

Wrong:

`use babel
import { bla } from 'blub'`

Correct:

`use babel
import { bla } from 'blub'`